# Is this Cat5 or Cat5e

Tags: cable

I bought some Cat5e cable for my house data wire however the coil that is delivered clearly says Cat5. The shop say it is 5e as they don't stock 5.

Can anyone tell for sure?

[image: cable]

[image: info]

Comment: Also look on the side of the cable. I find this often does not match the packaging, exactly, and may state 5e.

Answer (score 2):

Unless that cable is *really* old (check the *(c) 2021* mark), *Category 5* and *Category 5e* are the exact same thing.

In the inital Cat5 standard (1990s), some crosstalk parameters had been overlooked. These were subsequently added as Cat5e (2001) - which a few years later got relabeled as just *Category 5*.